# onPostExecute is called twice and showing double result

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to download some files in background, for that I used download manager and I made this method:

```
/*** media download ***/
    public long mediaDownload(ArrayList<DownloadedFile> arrayList, String foldPathName) {
        long downloadReference = 0;

        // Create request for android download manager
        downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size();i++){

            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(arrayList.get(i).getUri());
            request.setTitle("Data Download");
            request.setDescription("New media");

            //Set the local destination for the downloaded file to a path
            //within the application's external files directory
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/" + folder_main + "/" + foldPathName, arrayList.get(i).getName());
            File f = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/" + folder_main + "/" + foldPathName + "/" + arrayList.get(i).getName());
            Log.e("File:",f.toString());

            //Enqueue download and save into referenceId
            downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

        }
        return downloadReference;
    }
```

I have a picture and a Video to download for test, and when checking downloaded file in Explorer I find 2 videos and 2 picture, debug that I found that onPostExecute method is called twice and I can't figure out why.

Here is my onPostExecute method:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                    JSONArray region = null;
                    region = jsonObject.getJSONArray("regions");
                    Log.e("Regions:", String.valueOf(region.length()));
                    for (int i = 0; i < region.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject json_data = region.getJSONObject(i);
                            int height_view = Integer.parseInt(json_data.getString("height"));
                            int width_view = Integer.parseInt(json_data.getString("width"));
    
                            int left_view = Integer.parseInt(json_data.getString("left"));
                            int top_view = Integer.parseInt(json_data.getString("top"));
                            int right_view = Integer.parseInt(json_data.getString("right"));
                            int bottom_view = Integer.parseInt(json_data.getString("bottom"));
    
                            /**** Media in region ***/
                            JSONObject media = json_data.getJSONObject("media");
                            String type_media = media.getString("type");
    
                            url = media.getString("url");
                            name = media.getString("name");
                            uri = Uri.parse(url);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        downloadedFiles.add(new DownloadedFile(name, uri));
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Layout Created with" + height + "x" + width, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.e("Downloaded Files:",downloadedFiles.toString());
                mediaDownload(downloadedFiles, folderName); // region media's download
            }
```

On my logcat I see that my arrayList has 2 elements, but displayed twice, which means files are downloaded twice so the onPostExecute method called 2 times, thanks for help.

Comment: Maybe you are calling it twice, check it again.

Comment: No its only one time

Comment: Post full code, of where you are calling it and the full Async class.

Comment: is your `onPostExecute` a method overriden in AsyncTask?

Comment: first check size of downloadedFiles array size   on mediaDownload(downloadedFiles, folderName) call..
Then try removing this line...
 File f = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/" + folder_main + "/" + foldPathName + "/" + arrayList.get(i).getName());
            Log.e("File:",f.toString());

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko yes it is

Comment: @kubersingh both of them showing 2 files, but both executed twice cause they are logged in onPostExecute

Comment: show how you use asynctask then

Comment: check if the calling of asyntask not in any loop..

Comment: am calling it in `onCreate` this way :  `new dispProj().execute();` and there is no loop in there

Comment: check in debug with a breakpoint if you are calling it twice

Comment: yes may be oncreate call twice due to Activity Tasks instance calling it twice..

Comment: i've checked using breakpoint, i can't find out why it's called twice and i have no other loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out after passing my time debugging all the code, when the activity is created it changes the screen orientation and so it creates a second instance, so my AsyncTask is called twice and thats why i thought onPosteExecute is called twice, thanks for everyone who tried to help.